# Displaying Video in an HTML5 (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, video-streaming, html5-video

I used the attached tutorial for obtaining a video that is returned in the form of ActionResult, returned from controller. In below implementation, it is impossible to seek a video forward, to frames that are yet to be loaded.

Could you please suggest how could I achieve this goal?

[MVC Tips Play or Display Video an ASP.NET MVC](http://jayeshsorathia.blogspot.com/2014/04/mvc-tips-play-or-display-video-in-asp-net-mvc.html)